# How could one draw a semibreve (whole note) in Java Swing?

Tags: java, graphics, notation

I am creating a class to handle the creation of musical notation in my music training app, which is being built with Java Swing. As such, I am using the font Bravura for most of the symbols such as the treble clef and accidentals (using the Graphics drawString method with unicode characters).

However, I am unable to find a way to draw a semibreve, or a whole note, with this method; I get a rectangle instead of the desired character when I input the sequence `"\uD834\uDD5D"`, which should correspond to a whole note, according to my research using [fileformat.info](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d15d/index.htm).

My code for the JFrame is below:

```
public MusicalNotation() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    
    JTextArea semibreveTextArea = new JTextArea();
    semibreveTextArea.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 200);
    semibreveTextArea.setFont(new Font("Bravura", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    semibreveTextArea.setText("\uD834\uDD5D");
    contentPane.add(semibreveTextArea);
    semibreveTextArea.setBackground(getBackground());
    semibreveTextArea.setEditable(false);
}
```

However, the resulting window looks like the below:

[image]
Are there any other fonts which have this functionality, or other ways to draw a semibreve?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Are there any other fonts which have this functionality?`. Yes there are (several) and and one of them is the font you are already using.

The **Bravura** music font already contains the Semibreve and you shouldn't need to draw anything since **Bravura** is a font. All you need to do is provide the appropriate Unicode value for the notes, lines, and spacing you want and of course, the `"\uD834\uDD5D"` is valid for displaying the Semibreve note providing the Text component you are displaying the characters in has the **Bravura** font set to it (not all fonts support all of these Unicode music characters), for example:

```
try {
    // Load the "Bravura.otf" font file.
    Font bravura = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("Bravura.otf"));
    // Font Size - NEEDED! I believe default is 1. 
    // Set it to what you want but you may find 
    // size 12 too small.
    bravura = bravura.deriveFont(36f); 
    // Set the font to a JTextArea (or whatever).
    jTextArea1.setFont(bravura);
    // Display the Semibreve.
    jTextArea1.setText("\uD834\uDD5D");
}
catch (FontFormatException | IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

You should see a Semibreve within the JTextAea.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your response. Following your advice, I implemented the code in the question - but the same problem arises. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If on a MAC you may need to install the Bravura font with the [Installer](https://github.com/steinbergmedia/bravura).